Send email with basic authentication
For more than 10 years, all our family PCs used sendemail with a dedicated outlook account to confirm success or failure of daily backup jobs via (1) rsync backup script and also (2) backintime.  Microsoft has recently tightened its outlook smtp to require stronger controls.  Does anyone know of a more basic free gateway I can switch to that still works?
